# Django + WSGI: Force object initialization?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have a form class that looks something like this:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = Field(model_field='username', filters=validators.minlength(3))
```

You'll notice that `username` is a class variable. I believe this means that `Field` will be constructed *once* the first time the `RegisterForm` is used (after apache is restarted). It will not be re-constructed between page reloads (unless a 2nd *WSGI instance* (?) is spawned, but we won't get into that). I noticed this because some of the values I've set in `Field.__init__` are not being reset.

However, `Form.__init__` *does* seem to be called each page reload. I guess that's because of the way I'm using it? I'm actually constructing it like `form = RegisterForm(request)` at each page request.

So... supposing I don't want the [class variables in] `RegisterForm` to be "cached" and have the `Fields` re-initialized at each request... how would I do that? (without modifying the syntax of `RegisterForm`; you can do whatever inside the base class, `Form`)

Answer (score 0):

You could update the class variable each instantiation:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    username = Field(model_field='username', filters=validators.minlength(3))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ContactForm.username = Field(model_field='username', filters=validators.minlength(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the class within a function. That way it gets constructed each time the function is called.

```
def gotclass(data):
  class InnerClass(object):
    someattr = DoSomethingWith(data)
  return InnerClass

MyNewClass = gotclass(42)
someobj = MyNewClass()
```